# jquery featherlight on dynamic content from DataTalbes

Tags: datatables, featherlight.js

I am using jquery featherlight (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) after trying to get jquery lightbox (https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) to work. I am using DataTables to generate a list. One of the items in the table is a link to a php page that returns links. The problem is I am calling an external PHP page that generates a list of links. So my link code is like this:

```
<a href="/code/lenker.php?q=Abies alba" class="show_link" title="Show links for Abies alba"><i class="fas fa-link fa-lg"></i></a>
```

The page "lenker.php" does a search and outputs html code. It looks fine in the chrome inspector. But the popup is empty. If I link to another page with the code hardcoded it shows fine. Why does it not show when it is generated on the fly? The html code looks just fine like this:

```
<div><a class="external" href="http://databank.artsdatabanken.no/FremmedArt2012/N63753" data-featherlight="ajax">fremmedartsvurdering 2012 for edelgran</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="http://eol.org/pages/1033070" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran hos Encyclopedia of Life</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="http://linnaeus.nrm.se/flora/barr/pina/abies/abiealb.html" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran i Virtuella floran, Sverige</a></div>
```

but the popup opens and then resizes to almost nothing since there is no content. Featherlight does not need any other initialization since it looks for **data-featherlight="ajax"**.

Is the problem that datatable is dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax expects one object so I solved this with enclosing my content in one DIV.